# VMware 10 and Linux guest OS: how to change NIC driver from vmxnet3 to vmxnet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ethernet, vmware-workstation

Guest OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Host OS: Windows 7
VMware Workstation 10

Problem:
vmware tools automatically install vmxnet3 driver, without an option to select nic driver.
In .vmx, ethernet0.virtualDev = "e1000".
So ethernet0.virtualDev **doesn't decide which driver** to be used.

How to change NIC driver from vmxnet3 to vmxnet?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding a second adapter?  Choose the type you want, then delete your first one?  Then you would need to change the config file and edit any IDs are MAC that was tied to the first adapter and put in the info for the second adapter